# ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute +CSV: How to loop through the columns returned?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I have a SQL statements that I retrieve records:

```
def total_sales_category_csv

  query1 = "SELECT categoryname, casecost, product_name..."

  result1 = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query1)

  query2 = "SELECT categoryname, foo, bar..."

  result2 = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query2)

  result3 =  "SELECT SUM(inv_figures1.available) ..."

  bottle_sum = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query_for_bottle_sum)


  report = FasterCSV.generate do |csv|
    csv << %w{Category casecost product_name Total Sales Avg}

    #I'm stuck here
  end

end
```

So at the part that I'm stuck, how do I loop through the records returned by my `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute` in an object oriented way? Can I do something like this:

```
  report = FasterCSV.generate do |csv|
    csv << %w{Category casecost product_name Total Sales Avg}
    result1.each do |row|
      csv << [result1.categoryname, result2[0].foo] 

    end
  end
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your result is a hash with column name as keys. So you access them like below

```
result1.each do |row|
  csv << [result1["categoryname"], result2[0]["foo"]] 

end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using custom SQL just to fetch records, I recommend using find_by_sql like this:

```
query1 = "SELECT categoryname, casecost, product_name..."
result1 = MyModel.find_by_sql(query1)

result1.each do |row|
  csv << [row.categoryname, row.casecost, row.product_name]
end
```

find_by_sql returns an array of activerecord objects, so then you're just looping over the array.